# Generar archivo CSV desde una consulta SQL

Tags: postgresql

Estoy trabajando con PostgreSQL 9.6, intenté poner:

```
 COPY (SELECT * FROM estado) TO E'"C:\\Users\\freqde\\Documents\\A.csv"';
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
 no se permiten rutas relativas para COPY hacia un archivo
```

Comment: Intentó con  `COPY (SELECT * FROM estado) TO 'C:\\Users\\freqde\\Documents\\A.csv' ;`  ya que esta es la estructura de `COPY` claro como posibilidad de agregar un delimitador. **¿Desea realizar algo más especifico?**

Comment: A que entorno se refiere? o en cual necesita?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trata de eliminar las dobles comillas:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM estado) TO E'C:\\Users\\freqde\\Documents\\A.csv';
```

Recuerda que si tu base de datos no está en tu ordenador, la copia la intentará hacer en el ordenador remoto en el que esté esa base de datos.

Comment: Marco, ¿esa "E" esta demás?

Comment: Hola Pedro, sirve con ambas. Lo importante es especificar bien una ruta sobre la que nuestro usuario `postgres` (o el que hayas definido para la base de datos) tenga permisos de escritura. Recuerda que en windows hay que especificar dos barras invertidas `\\\` para indicar el salto a una nueva carpeta.

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La facil es dar click en el campo **Export data to file** arriba en el panel e indicar la ruta que queremos.

Comment: y si no usa un entorno asi como el tuyo?

Answer (score -1):

Yo utilicé de la siguiente manera y funcionó correctamente:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tabla) TO E'/folder1/folder2/archivo.csv';
```

También modifiqué los permisos públicos del archivo csv para escritura.

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner código, dale editar y explícalo